# Limit for included records in Loopback4

Tags: strongloop, loopback, loopback4

I want to query Exercise model objects and include related objects (relation: athletExerciseLogsExercise). But I need only 1 related object, thats why I add "limit: 1" to inclusion scope:

```
exerciseController.find({
    include: [{
        relation: "athletExerciseLogsExercise",
        scope: {
            where: {
                userId: id
            },
            order: ['date DESC'],
            limit: 1
        }
    }, ]
});
```

Model

```
export class Exercise extends Entity {
  ...
  @hasMany(() => AthletExerciseLog, {keyTo: 'exerciseId'})
  athletExerciseLogsExercise?: AthletExerciseLog[];
  ...
}
```

SQL (from debug)

```
SELECT
  "id",
  "userid",
  "exerciseid",
  "date"
  ...
FROM
  "public"."athletexerciselog"
WHERE
  "userid" = '65b9b7110230'
  AND "exerciseid" IN (
    'd67503d511bb',
    '46d156a58aee'
  )
ORDER BY  "date" DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**Problem**: SQL result contains only 1 record **for one** "exerciseid" = 'd67503d511bb'

**Question**: how to receive 1 record from "athletexerciselog" **for each** "exerciseid" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution, it might be an overhead, but I couldn't find another way...

1 - Create DB View: select only 1 (last) record for each **userid** and **exerciseid**

```
CREATE VIEW "v_athletexerciselog" AS  
  SELECT q.*
  FROM athletexerciselog q
  WHERE (
        q.id IN ( 
          SELECT max(i.id) AS max
           FROM athletexerciselog i
          WHERE (i.event IS NULL)
          GROUP BY i.userid, i.exerciseid
        )
  )
```

2 - Create a new LB4 Model *and Repository*
extends original model with custom table name (view name)

```
@model({
  settings: {
    postgresql: {schema: 'public', table: 'v_athletexerciselog'}, // custom names
  },
})
export class VAthletExerciseLog extends AthletExerciseLog {
  constructor(data?: Partial<VAthletExerciseLog>) {
    super(data);
  }
}
```

3 - change related model name in Exercise model *and repository* to VAthletExerciseLog (new)

```
export class Exercise extends Entity {
  ...
  @hasMany(() => VAthletExerciseLog, {keyTo: 'exerciseId'})
  athletExerciseLogsExercise?: VAthletExerciseLog[];
  ...
}
```

4 - Remove "order" and "limit" from query:

```
exercise.find({
    include: [{
        relation: "athletExerciseLogsExercise",
        scope: {
            where: {
                userId: id
            },
            //order: ['date DESC'],
            //limit: 1
        }
    }, ]
});
```